# Корректные права на ссылку папки

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, chmod

есть папка `web` в ней находится ссылка на папку `~uploads`, внутри нее есть так же куча папок и подпапок, права на нее ставил так: `sudo chmod -R 0777 web/uploads`, и это вроде как работает, картинки сохраняются в некоторых случаях не удаляя ссылку, но есть такие случаи когда после записи новой картинки удаляется ссылка и на месте нее создается папка `uploads`, и внутри нее папка и файл который сохранился, а всего остального понятно что нет, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту проблему

```
    var uploadBtn = $(element);
    var uploadContainer = uploadBtn.closest('.uploader-container');
    var uploader = uploadBtn.data('uploader');
    var url = uploadBtn.data('uploader-url');
    var type = uploadBtn.data('uploader-type');

    switch (uploader)
    {
        case 'dropzone':
            var dz = uploadBtn.dropzone({
                url: url,
                previewTemplate: '<span class="hidden"></span>',
                filesizeBase: 1024,
                maxFilesize: (type === 'image' ? 8 : 2),
                init: function () {

                    this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
                        var filter = uploadBtn.data('image-filter') || false;

                        if (false !== filter) {
                            formData.append('filter_name', filter);
                        }

                        uploadContainer.block();
                    });

                    this.on('success', function (file, response) {
                        if (type === 'file') {
                            var downloadBtn = uploadContainer.find('.uploader-download');
                            var emptyBtn = uploadContainer.find('.uploader-empty');
                            var input = uploadContainer.find('.uploader-input');

                            if (downloadBtn.length) {
                                downloadBtn.attr('href', response.url);
                                downloadBtn.removeClass('hidden');
                            }

                            if (input.length) {
                                input.val(response.url);
                            }

                            if (emptyBtn.length) {
                                emptyBtn.remove();
                            }
                        } else if (type === 'image') {
                            uploadBtn.attr('src', response.displayUrl ? response.displayUrl : response.url);
                        }
                    });

                    this.on('error', function (file, response, xhr) {
                        if (undefined !== xhr) {
                            if (response.message) {
                                FLASHES.addFlash('error', Translator.trans(response.message));
                            } else if (response.error) {
                                FLASHES.addFlash('error', Translator.trans(response.error));
                            } else {
                                FLASHES.addFlash('error', Translator.trans('upload.error.generic'));
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($.type(response) === 'string') {
                                FLASHES.addFlash('error', Translator.trans(response));
                            }
                        }

                        uploadContainer.unblock();
                    });

                    this.on('complete', function (file) {
                        this.removeFile(file);
                        uploadContainer.unblock();
                    });
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Wrong uploader type');
    }
});
```

Comment: Может можно как то сделать что бы разрешить создавать файлы и папки, но запретить удалять их путем перезаписывания или еще как либо

Comment: Ничего не понятно: кто какие папки создаёт, кто какие папки удаляет, кто пишет файлы и так далее. Покажите код, который всем этим занимается, или иным образом расскажите, кто что конкретно делает

Comment: @andreymal извините сейчас попытаюсь объяснить, уже удалось чуть больше выяснить. Есть 2 сервера на ubuntu(стейдж и прод), код на них идентичен. Когда я пытаюсь изменить картинку библиотека js удаляет старую и загружает новую, но вместо удаления самой картинки удаляет полностью ссылку на папку, сейчас вопрос только в том как защитить ссылку на папку от такого поведения, помогают права 644 но тогда и ничего туда записать нельзя

Comment: Вопрос в том, кто и почему удаляет ссылку на папку. Поставьте права 644 не на ссылку, а на папку, в котором лежит ссылка

Comment: не знаю почему так сделано, но в папке web ссылка на папку uploads, uploads размещена вне директории сайта, если 644 поставить на папку это как то запретит удаление ссылки на эту папку?

Comment: 644 запрещает записывать новые файлы

Comment: Значит, видимо, без кода, занимающегося записыванием файлов и удалением ссылок, дальнейший конструктивный разговор вряд ли получится

Comment: я же говорю что на двух серверах идентичен код, на одном удаляет ссылку на втором нет, к коду вопросов вообще никаких нет

Comment: У вас, может, и нет, зато у меня очень даже есть. Нужен код

Comment: Прикрепи, можете посмотреть

Comment: В данном коде нет ничего, что взаимодействовало бы с папкой `uploads` или её содержимым. Вы прикрепили явно что-то не то

Comment: есть еще yml конфиг в котором прописываются пути для работы библиотеки dropzone

Comment: в конфиге мы задаем путь к папке uploads, а здесь передаем файл, и вызываем нужные обработчики, а библиотека уже внутри выполняет нужные действия

Comment: Dropzone [не содержит серверой части](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation) и в принципе не может управлять папкой `uploads`. Непонятно, о какой ещё «библиотеке dropzone» речь